# How to translate a warning message?

Tags: i18n-l10n

There is a code
`define('SPAMBOT_DEFAULT_BLOCKED_MESSAGE', 'Your email address or username or IP address is blacklisted.');`
How to make the phrase 'Your email address or username or IP address is blacklisted.' translatable? (with t).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how often it appears, you can call `t(SPAMBOT_DEFAULT_BLOCKED_MESSAGE)` every time you invoke the constant in your code. For instance:

```
<?php

define('SPAMBOT_DEFAULT_BLOCKED_MESSAGE', 'Your email address or username or IP address is blacklisted.');

/**
 * implement hook_page_alter()
 * JUST AN EXAMPLE. REPLACE WITH YOUR OWN HOOK OR FUNCTION
 */
function mymodule_page_alter(&$page) {
  drupal_set_message(t(SPAMBOT_DEFAULT_BLOCKED_MESSAGE));
}
```

In order to be able to see the string in the "Translate interface" page (`admin/config/regional/translate/translate`), you need to display it at least once in a language different from the default language of your site.

Comment: It was tested and it didn't work.

Comment: @gladiatorhl2, I have just tested it and it worked fine for me in a Drupal 7 instance. I have just edited my answer with some details.

Comment: I replaced all the phrases SPAMBOT_DEFAULT_BLOCKED_MESSAGE by t(SPAMBOT_DEFAULT_BLOCKED_MESSAGE) inside the initial module. Does function mymodule_page_alter(&$page) must necessarily be used?

Comment: No, you can call t(SPAMBOT_DEFAULT_BLOCKED_MESSAGE) from anywhere in your code. However, you need to display the phrase in another language in your site, otherwise you won't see it in the "Translate Interface" page.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I ran cron but it doesn't appear in the "Translate Interface" page.